# Python Translation to C#

Tags: python

I am trying to convert Python to C#. There is one piece of python code which i am unable to understand. Please advise.

```
AppList = {
    "POLE" : set()
}

knownlist = AppList.get(ApplicationName.upper(),CardNumbers)
```

//ApplicationName is some string variable.

//CardNumbers is a collection of integer numbers.

Here is my question:

1. What is AppList here, is it a collection or some kind of Property like in C#?
2. How is AppList.get taking 2 parameters? What will be the output here?

Comment: `AppList` is a dictionary.

Comment: See the docs for the [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method.

Answer (score 2):

> What is AppList here, is it a collection or some kind of Property like
>   in C#?

AppList is dictionary in python.

> How is AppList.get taking 2 parameters? What will be the output here?

The method get() returns a value for the "ApplicationName.upper()". If "ApplicationName.upper()" is not available then returns default value Which is CardNumbers.

Comment: Thank you. So does the below code mean AppList dictionary contains an item called "POLE".
AppList = {
    "POLE" : set()
}

Comment: ***Yes*** @Rahul B